# how to load facebook page into webview after sso?

Tags: android, facebook, webview, single-sign-on

In my android app I've got the access token (valid, stored/retrieved into/from sharedPref). My question is if it's possible load a facebook page, say http://m.facebook.com/House into a webview as the current user?

It looks like a dark magic that the SDK can pickup the user session and use it in a webview by just doing a simple CookieSyncManager calls in the authorization process. Any idea how to do it in my own webview? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to fetch cookie from default browser or from account setup & then you just have to send it to your application's web-view.